# Need to work with mouse-over instead of dropdown

Tags: store-view, ce-1.9.2.2, script

we have multi store view site with countires : India, USA, France

on top of the site we can see those 3 countries, once we click on dropdown-button [here](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/)

[image]

what we need is instead of clicking on dropdown button, it should work with "mouse-over"

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Your Language:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried below 2 kind of codes, but it didt worked for me.

**code 1**:

```
$("#select-language").mouseover(window.location.href=this.value{
    $( "#select-language" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

**code 2**

```
<option onmouseover="window.location.href=this.value" 
value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a JavaScript only question and it's not related to Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select#select-language').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', jQuery('option').length);
  }, function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', 1);
  });
});
```

Add this Style to this select-box

```
select#select-language {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

There's also another **good solution**. You should convert `<select><option>...` to `<ul><li>...` list, and apply jQuery scipt as shown here in my answer : [Display the drop down values when mouse-over on text instead of textfield](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113941/display-the-drop-down-values-when-mouse-over-on-text-instead-of-textfield)

Comment: what i need to replace in place of `function` ?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: i updated your code, but its not working for me. i added script in same file - `languages.phtml` . please check [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/butterfly-love-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: edited the answer