# Display the drop down values when mouse-over on text instead of textfield

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, product-view, zoom

please visit [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/apple/iphone-4/filter/art_and_graphics.html)

on top left, you can see "**currenc**y" with dropdown box. once you mouse-over on that, you can see as below

[image]

in same link if you scroll down below you can see filters : `Device, Design, Category, Sort by`

once you mouse-over on **Design**, you can see like below image

[image]

I need same kind of functionality for "currency" also.

means, i want to remove the textfield.

once we mouse-over on "currency"  text , it should display drop-down values.

**code for currency**

**Script**

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select#select-language').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', jQuery('option').length);
  }, function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', 1);
  });
});

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
select#select-language {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-left: 4em;
padding-right: 2em;
}

option:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #0000FF;
}



</style>
```

**phtml**

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

when i use [template path hints](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/apple/iphone-4/filter/art_and_graphics.html?tp=1&code=magento) , i found this code for filters :

```
<!--<?php $_filters = $this->getActiveFilters() ?>

<?php $_removeTxt = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Remove This Item') ?>
<?php if (!empty($_filters)): ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('glace_navigationlayer')->isVersionLessThan(1, 4)): ?>
        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Currently Shopping by') ?></h4>
        <ol class="narrowed-category">
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Currently Shopping by') ?></p>
        <ol class="currently">    
    <?php endif; ?>

    -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert `<select><option>...` to `<ul><li>...` list, and apply jQuery scipt as shown here in demo : http://html-tuts.com/jquery-dropdown-menu/

**Full Solution:**

Change this phtml

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

WITH :

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>

    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' class="selected"' : '' ?>
                <li <?php echo $_selected ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now Apply Below jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#select-language li').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').stop(true, false, true).fadeToggle(300);
    });
});
</script>
```

Add some CSS (change it according to your requirement) :

```
<style type="text/css">
.menuBackground {
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropDownMenu a {
    color: #FFF;
}
.dropDownMenu,
.dropDownMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropDownMenu li {
    position: relative;
}
.dropDownMenu a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropDownMenu a:hover {
    background: #000;
}
.dropDownMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: -4px; /* solve the 4 pixels spacing between list-items */
}
.dropDownMenu > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.dropDownMenu ul {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
.dropDownMenu > li > ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
</style>
```

**Note:** Remove other `jQuery` or `CSS` binded with `select-language` element

Comment: i used option & select in script and css, is i have to change there also ?

Comment: check answer with Full Solution

Comment: updated, please check link. dropdown values are missing.

Comment: updated jQuery code, please apply it

Comment: please check link, dropdown values are displaying too much below.

Comment: dropdown is working for "your language" , i want for "currency"

Comment: Now you can change HTML and CSS for `select-language` element yourself, dropdown feature is working, right ? : )

Comment: okay boss, i will try for that. but plese help me for displaying dropdown for currency instead of "your language"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39285/discussion-between-anil-suthar-and-user9999).